# Postfix Conf - Unknown user

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, email-bounces

Can't receive emails for virtual users but they can send.
UNIX users that can receive and sent. What am I doing wrong?

```
root@localhost: postconf -n
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/postgresql/virtual.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:1000
virtual_mailbox_base = ~/maildir
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/postgresql/boxes.cf
virtual_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/postgresql/virtual.cf
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:1000
```

Error

```
to=<test@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.09/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "test")
```

virtual.cf: `alias_email => email`

boxes.cf: `username => /home/username`

transport.cf: `email => 'virtual'`

virtual.cf **input**: example_alias@example.com **returns**: test@example.com

```
table=v_alias
select_field=alias
where_field=email
hosts=localhost
```

boxes.cf **input**: test **returns**: /home/test

```
table=auth
select_field=maildir
where_field=username
hosts=localhost
```

transport.cf **input**: test@example.com **returns**: virtual:

```
table=mail_transport
select_field=transport
where_field=domain
hosts=localhost
```

DB Setup:

```
class auth():
    user        = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username    = CharField(max_length=255)
    password    = CharField(max_length=255)
    maildir     = CharField(max_length=255)

class v_alias():
    user        = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alias       = CharField(max_length=255)
    email       = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    status      = IntegerField(choices=ADDRESS_STATUS, default=1)


class mail_transport():
    domain      = CharField(max_length=255)
    transport   = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/postfix/postgresql/virtual.cf` and in the database are crucial. This question cannot be answered without knowing them.

Comment: Updated the question, hope it helps. Please let me know what you think. I've spend a few days on this, without proper guidance or understanding of what I'm doing.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Am I missing something there? Or am I doing something wrong?